# Inconsistency in Unicode with wchar_t vs. ICU in C++

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, icu

While `wchar_t` is inconsistent in case of support on different compilers, but is it safe to assume `wchar_t` implementation and size are similar in GNU/GCC at least on Linux ?

Despite to the fact that `wchar_t` size has system architecture  dependency in terms of bit-size (32bit/64bit) is Wide Character Type on Linux (GNU/GCC) actually compiler dependent or libstdc++ libraries dependent?  I mean by changing or upgrading which one I should consider that `wchar_t` might not work as expected in terms of size  and support

While [IBM ICU](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/icu/)  is another option, can it be used in conjunction with `std::string` ?

Should I totally dismiss `wchar_t` in favor of ICU?

*Note:* On Unix Like Operating Systems such as Linux with GNU/GCC libstdc++ brings core C++ functionality to the compiler, thus occasionally updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to present strings to the user, you might have to take `wchar_t` (or some other library defined type) into consideration. Different compilers and platforms define `wchar_t` differently, because they use different Unicode encoding techniques. On Windows/Visual C++ for instance, `wchar_t` is a 16 bit type, suitable for UTF-16. On GCC/Linux for instance, `wchar_t` is a 32 bit type, suitable for UTF-32.

The IBM ICU library has conversion functions for transforming from one encoding to another. Your platform (Win32 for instance) might also have functions for transforming from one encoding to another.

Depending on your requirements (speed, memory usage), you should pick an internal format that suits the platform. On Windows it might be UTF-16, and on Linux it might be UTF-32. That way you won't have to transcode strings all the time, just to make simple platform-defined operations on them (`wcslen()`, `wcscmp()`, etc).

For external formats (text files, etc), I tend to use UTF-8. The reason is that files are considerably smaller if they contain text in a western language. Another benefit is that you don't have to consider endianess in UTF-8, which makes the chance of errors (on your or some other's part) less likely.

The IBM ICU is a very big and competent library for handling Unicode strings. Although, it might be using a sledge hammer to drive in a small nail. Do you need all of its functionality? The Unicode functionality supported by the target platform might meet your requirements.

Comment: Jorgen, You are Using UTF-8, is it safe to store UTF-8 within std::string as it is fundamentally nothing but characters (char compatible), and avoid ICU, ICU is very large package, and what I'm working on needs to be Unicode Safe but does not require string manipulation

Comment: Yes, it is safe to store UTF-8 within std::string. However, the length()-method will not work properly, unless there's some magic in the C++ runtime to treat all char-based strings as UTF-8. length() normally just counts the number of bytes in the string, and not the number of characters. As you may know, some characters in UTF-8 may take up to four bytes of storage. If this is not a concern for you, then you can easily use std::string as a container.

Comment: @Jörgen Sigvardsson: Note that `std::wstring::length()` on Win32 doesn't return the number of characters in the string either.

Comment: @Jörgen Sigvardsson: Yes exactly, a character encoded in UTF-16 may take up 1 or 2 code units, thus `std::wstring::length()` on Win32 doesn't return the number of characters in the string: It return the number of code units in the string, which is, by no mean, the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It used to be easy with UCS-2, but those days are gone unless you develop for NT 4 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes, `wchar_t` can change with a new compiler version (it is a language feature though, not a library one, so it doesn't depend on libraries).

In practice, the odds of it suddenly changing size are pretty much zero.

It's not really clear what you actually *need* though. `wchar_t` just allows you to store wide characters, and not much more. ICU is a complete unicode library which does a lot more, and is pretty much essential if you want to do more complex text processing than simply printing strings.

Finally, on *nix, plain `char`'s, or `std::string` usually use an UTF-8 encoding, so those are perfectly suitable for storing Unicode text.  `wchar_t` is rarely used for that reason.

Comment: libstdc++  on Linux is the library of GNU/GCC that brings core C++ functionality to the compiler,  thus what you claimed regarding libraries in this case does not seem to be correct,

Comment: @kay: how do you figure? libstc++ is the standard c++ library implementation, as the name implies. The size of various datatypes is defined by by the compiler itself.

Comment: jalf, I know LIBSTDC++ is what it is: you can spend some time and read here, also check what I asked     http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/

Comment: @kay: I did read what you asked. Here, let me quote it, in case you forgot: "is Wide Character Type on Linux (GNU/GCC) actually compiler dependent or libstdc++ libraries dependent? I mean by changing or upgrading which one I should consider that wchar_t might not work as expected in terms of size and support". And my answer: `wchar_t` is a core language feature, and can only change with the compiler, not the standard library. I'm not really sure what that link is supposed to tell me.

Comment: jalf,  it seems it is not clear for you, wchar_t is for representation of Unicode,  the standard library in C++ like std::cout and others will break that consistency over different versions, I tested it and this is why I asked that, on any new libstdc++, wchar_t representation with older library is broken,  especially if you use standard library

Comment: You're right, it's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking if the size of `wchar_t` may change? Or if the encoding it uses may change? (whatever that means, since C++ doesn't really specify any encoding). Are you simply asking how to store unicode text in C++ strings?